# the reverse of .append() (delete elements)

Tags: jquery

I have some buttons with id's and a "result box", on pressing any button my jquery code takes the button id and place it in the result box.
One of the buttons is a "delete" button, this button should delete the last placed id using the code `$("#resultbox").remove( x );` but it doesn't
here's my code:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    x = event.target.id; //takes the id of the button
    switch (x)
    {
    case "del":
        **$("#resultbox").remove( x ); //here it should delete last placed id but it doesn't work**
        break;
    default:
        $( "#resultbox" ).append( x );
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: `event` is not defined in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix `id` with `#` in the selector parameter of `remove()`, If you have to remove the descendant of `#resultbox`.

```
$("#resultbox").remove( "#"+ x );
```

As id of element is supposed to be unique, you can directly delete the element

```
$("#"+ x).remove();
```

**Edit** based on comments and live demo

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w2kG6/2/)**

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    x = this.id;    
    switch (x)
    {
    case "del":
        text = $("#resultbox").text( )
        $("#resultbox").text(text.substring(0,text.length-1)); 
        break;
    default:
        $( "#resultbox" ).append( x );
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: To  delete all the text you need, $("#resultbox").text("")

Answer (score 1):

What is `event`?

You should specify as a parameter:

```
$( "button" ).click(function(event) {
```

Check [jQuery click documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

> handler(eventObject)
>
> Type: Function()
>
> A function to execute each time the event is triggered.

Also, you are adding elements just by text, so you can remove like this:

```
$( "button" ).click(function(event) {
    var id = this.id; // the actual button
    switch (id)
    {
        case "del":
            var text = $("#resultbox").text();
            if (text.length >= 1)
            {
                text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
                $("#resultbox").text(text);
            }
            break;
        default:
            $( "#resultbox" ).append(id);
            break;
    }
});
```

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2kG6/1/).

Comment: ohh it's working now, thank you very much.
Can you tell me which better, your answer or the one that I accepted?

Comment: @System32 the one you accepted use `x` without declaring it, which may cause a error, depends on your whole code context. But for temp vars like that you should always declare it inside your function. Declare once `var x` instead of just using `x` without that declaration.

Answer (score 1):

This is the working calculator for you..

You were seriously messed the id selector code. I tried improving it..

**http://jsfiddle.net/w2kG6/3/**

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    var _self = $(this);
    var _attr = _self.attr('id');

    console.log(_attr);
    switch (_attr)
    {
    case "del":
        var str = $("#resultbox").text();
        if($("#resultbox").length > 0)
            $("#resultbox").html(str.substring(0,str.length - 1))
        break;
    default:
        $( "#resultbox" ).append( _attr );
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: ohh it's working now, thank you very much. Can you tell me which better, your answer or the both down?

Comment: This one is much better... :-) hit upvote / tick as answer if you think this is the right answer. Let's help others!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this :

```
$('#result').last().remove();
```

This will pick up the last element in the container and remove it..

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like this. X is a copy of what you're appending, not the appended element itself. As for that, $......append will return an object which is what you just created. If you provide this object to the remove statement, it will work as expected.